# Google Cloud Logging Driver cannot find credentials after reboot

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, systemd, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've followed the directions [here](https://dertompson.com/2019/01/19/how-to-send-docker-logs-to-google-cloud-logging/), and everything works well until I restart my computer. After restarting, it seems like the docker daemon loses track of the Google credentials.

```
$ docker run --log-driver=gcplogs ...
```

fails with:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

This is strange to me, because running `$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker` returns the value in my systemd configuration:

```
Environment=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/etc/path/to/application_default_credentials.json
```

If I `$ sudo systemctl restart docker`, then docker runs sucessfully and logs are sent to stackdriver. But I want this docker image to run automatically on startup, and restarting docker with `sudo` gets in the way.

Is there a way to initialize the docker daemon with the necessary environment variables, so gcplogs is ready on boot without restarting docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two versions of docker installed -- one through adding docker's repo to apt, and one through snap. Running

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files| grep docker | grep enabled
```

showed two installations of docker:

```
docker.service                             enabled    
snap.docker.dockerd.service                enabled
```

Having two docker installations was causing problems for startup. I removed the snap installation, rebooted, and everything now works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may try to edit the [systemd: Unit dependencies and order](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/), let docker.service start after google-accounts-daemon.service.

You can see all the service in google vm by

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files| grep google | grep enabled
```

And you will see

```
google-accounts-daemon.service             enabled
google-clock-skew-daemon.service           enabled
google-instance-setup.service              enabled
google-network-daemon.service              enabled
google-shutdown-scripts.service            enabled
google-startup-scripts.service             enabled
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Running list-unit-files through "grep google" didn't give me any results, but got me on the path of debugging with list-unit-files, which was the ticket. I had installed docker through both apt and snap, which apparently caused problems with their startups. Removing docker from snap fixed the issue.